# I want to disable next two values too in select dropdown dynamically

Tags: php, wordpress

i am making event calendar and when a user booked a time then other users will not able to select that time plus next two time slots
like we have 3:00 AM, 3:30 AM, 4:00 AM to onward till 24 hrs and if user selects 3:00 AM then 3:30 AM and 4:00 AM will also be disabled.

I have disabled 3:00 AM but i am not finding a way to disable 3:30 AM and 4:00 Am slot dynamically.

```
$date = '20190713';

$taken_slots  = array(); 
$bookings_qry = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT booked_end_time FROM    wp_booked_time WHERE booked_date=$date");

foreach($bookings_qry as $bookings_row)
$taken_slots[] = $bookings_row->booked_end_time;

$slots_qry = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_time");
$calendar  = '<select>'; 
$calendar .= '<option value="select" disabled="disabled">Select a Time</option>';

foreach($slots_qry as $slots_row){

$slot_id = $slots_row->time_id;

$calendar .= '<option value="'.$slot_id.'"';

 if(in_array($slot_id, $taken_slots)) 

   $calendar .= 'disabled="disabled"'; 


$calendar .= '>';    
$calendar.= $slots_row->times.'</option>';

}

$calendar .= '</select>';

echo $calendar;
```

in above code i am fetching time from wp_time table and matching booked values from wp_booked_time table from database. Please help me now how i can disable next two values. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The best way to manipulate time (and iterate through time intervals) is to use native PHP DateTime, DateInterval, and DatePeriod. You need to check if the current unit interval overlaps with an existing appointment. Next step would be checking if the time slot selected is long enough for the selected/required number of units. There is room for further customization but this should (I hope) point you in the right direction.

```
<?php
/* Example "Office" or entity business rules (possibly loaded from DB?) */
$officeOpenTime = '08:00:00'; // 8am open
$officeCloseTime = '17:00:00'; // 5pm close
$officeMinPerUnit = 15; //Appt unit is 15 minutes long
$officeApptMinUnits = 2; //Appt minumum duration is 2 units (30 minutes)

/* Convert office minPerUnit to more useful DateInterval */
$unitInterval = new \DateInterval('PT'.$officeMinPerUnit.'M');

/* Day selected [presumably] from input */
$curSelectedDate = '2019-07-09';

/* Convert office open and close times to usable DateTime */
$curSelectedDayOfficeOpenDatetime = new \DateTime($curSelectedDate.' '.$officeOpenTime);
$curSelectedDayOfficeCloseDatetime = new \DateTime($curSelectedDate.' '.$officeCloseTime);

/* Iterable period per unit */
$curSelectedDayUnits = new \DatePeriod($curSelectedDayOfficeOpenDatetime, $unitInterval, $curSelectedDayOfficeCloseDatetime);

/* Current bookings test dataset- represents data from DB (make sure to ALWAYS order by datetime ascending)
 * Example (using open/close times):
 * SELECT * FROM appointments WHERE start_datetime < '2019-07-09 17:00:00' AND end_datetime > '2019-07-09 08:00:00' ORDER BY start_datetime ASC
 */
$testAppts = [
    [
        'start_datetime' => '2019-07-09 08:00:00',
        'end_datetime' => '2019-07-09 09:00:00'
    ],
    [
        'start_datetime' => '2019-07-09 11:00:00',
        'end_datetime' => '2019-07-09 11:30:00'
    ],
    [
        'start_datetime' => '2019-07-09 14:00:00',
        'end_datetime' => '2019-07-09 15:00:00'
    ],
    [
        'start_datetime' => '2019-07-09 15:00:00',
        'end_datetime' => '2019-07-09 16:00:00'
    ],
    [
        'start_datetime' => '2019-07-09 16:00:00',
        'end_datetime' => '2019-07-09 17:00:00'
    ]
];

?>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <select>
                <option value="" disabled selected>Select a time</option>
<?php
$apptCurIndex = 0;
$numAppts = count($testAppts);

/* Convert first appt times to usable DateTime if exists */
if( $numAppts > 0 ){
    $curApptStartDatetime = new \DateTime($testAppts[$apptCurIndex]['start_datetime']);
    $curApptEndDatetime = new \DateTime($testAppts[$apptCurIndex]['end_datetime']);
}

foreach( $curSelectedDayUnits as $unitStartDatetime){
    echo '<option value="'.$unitStartDatetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s').'"';

    /* Does slot need checking? */
    if( $numAppts > 0 ){
        /* Does slot need to be locked? */
        $unitEndDatetime = (clone $unitStartDatetime)->add($unitInterval);
        if( $unitEndDatetime > $curApptStartDatetime ){
            echo ' disabled';
        }

        /* Does current appt need to be incremented */
        if( $apptCurIndex < $numAppts - 1 && $unitEndDatetime >= $curApptEndDatetime ){
            $apptCurIndex++;
            $curApptStartDatetime = new \DateTime($testAppts[$apptCurIndex]['start_datetime']);
            $curApptEndDatetime = new \DateTime($testAppts[$apptCurIndex]['end_datetime']);
        }

    }

    echo '>'.$unitStartDatetime->format('g:i a').'</option>';
}
```

Comment: can you please explain it further. i am not understanding how it will work in my case?

Comment: @SiteSoft Before I go further, please read code comments. Also can you please copy paste code and see if it actually does what you need it to?